# Effects of avoiding a snubber circuit?

Tags: mosfet, pwm, dc-motor

Do I need a snubber circuit across the motor here?. I implemented the circuit and checked it working fine so far without a snubber circuit. what are the possible problems that may arise in this circuitry? 
Motor Specs: 24v dc ,4kgcm,FLRPM:500,2A

[image: Schematic]

Comment: What possible good do you think C2 is doing?  I can't think of any unless you like toasty FETs.

Comment: I removed it as I came to know(from the answers on my previous post) its the cause of heating mosfet. Just forgot to change in the pic when i posted it again.

Answer (score 4):

You do have a snubber circuit: D1. It's a simple case of a [diode snubber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snubber#Diode_snubbers).

With D1 open, the energy stored in the motor's windings will have to go somewhere else. In this circuit, it will probably raise the voltage at the junction of the motor and Q1 until Q1's source-drain breakdown voltage is exceeded, and it begins to conduct in [avalanche mode](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/an/AN/AN-9034.pdf). For IRF744N, that looks like 55V. Of course, this puts a lot of stress on the MOSFET. It must be able to handle all the energy stored in the motor's inductance thermally. The datasheet also specifies a maximum repetitive avalanche energy of \$9.4mJ\$. If you can be sure the stored energy in the motor doesn't exceed that, and also that you don't exceed the thermal limits of the MOSFET, then you can operate without D1. However, given the complexity of calculating and designing for all of that, it's usually easier to just include D1. It's unlikely your motor is small enough to not exceed the MOSFET's limits anyhow.

Furthermore, if you are using PWM control here, the behavior of the motor will be very different without D1. The current in an inductor (motors being no exception) changes at a rate proportional to the voltage across them:

$$ v = L\frac{\mathrm{d}i}{\mathrm{d}t} $$

When Q1 is off, then \$v = 0.65V\$ with D1. The current will decrease slowly. Without D1, then \$v = 55V\$, and the current will decrease quickly. This means higher current ripple, and lower average current at a given duty cycle if D1 is open.

Comment: ... but perhaps that's the reference schematic for the question, which is whether D1 can be removed in the built circuit?

Answer (score 0):

When the transistor is shut off, then because the motor is highly inductive, it forces the same current to continue to flow. This can build a high voltage that can "zap" the MOSFET.

The diode provides a path for that current. It is not a good idea to omit the diode, even if empirical testing shows that your MOSFET is surviving without it.

That being said, the circuit you have here seems to have a soft start and stop. The gate voltage is ramped up and down by C2 charging through R3 and discharging through R2. The RC constant of the R2 C2 discharge is 12 ms (assuming from the polar capacitor symbol that the hard-to-read marking says 10 uF).

The soft turn off will reduce the inductive kick by ramping down the current rather than abruptly cutting off its path.